# Scripting engines benchmark

Tags: javascript, scripting, benchmarking

How or with what tool can I compare performance of Scripting engines or run a valid benchmark?

1. Jexl
2. Javascript
3. Groovy
4. Beanshell
5. Velocity
   ...

I want to check how much time take similar logic (executed X times) as

`if(${myVar} == "a") log.info("equals") else log.info("not equals")`

Comment: The question is unclear. Running a benchmark is very different from comparing benchmark results. Running a benchmark usually requires a specialized software like 3DBench, CPUBench or similar, but comparing the results can be done in Excel.

Comment: In addition, it's unclear what kind of performance you want to compare. Is it floating point calculations per second, integer calculations per second, memory usage for a specific calculation, lines of code to complete a certain task, time for compilation, delay until execution, throughput on the network, ...?

Comment: I want to check how much time take similar logic (executed X times) as `if(${myVar} == "a") log.info("equals") else log.info("not equals")`

Comment: Logging e.g. is a bad example, because access to the log file needs to be synchronized. Multithreaded programs will suffer from logging.

Comment: For JS there is https://jsperf.com/, otherwise you might perhaps want to play the language game: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/

Comment: I want to compare JS to other language so it's not helping and language game is irrelevant

Comment: You decided to play the game `if x log something else log something else`. Not much of a difference. But I'll stop commenting. Too chatty already.